# Is it possible to have a better sql editor for phpMyAdmin?

Tags: database, phpmyadmin

I am studying database systems and using MySQL and phpMyAdmin.

The editor that comes with phpMyAdmin is plain editor that does not highlight any special syntax like for example: gEdit in ubuntu.

Can I change the editor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update your phpMyAdmin. The latest version (3.5) has *exactly* what you describe.

Comment: There's a demo available [from their try page](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/try.php) where you can see the syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe some javascript libs (like CodeMirror.net) could add colors to phpMyAdmin editor but I think it's too much work with source code of phpMyAdmin.

It's better and faster to use others application.

For MySQL I use HeidiSQL (windows) or DBeaver (java = windows/linux/mac)

Answer (score 1):

phpMyAdmin is a security hole waiting to happen. I use **Navicat** over an SSH tunnel. It's a native connection function they have and Navicat works a lot nicer as a complete phpMyAdmin replacement. You're not any longer dependent on a huge and slow php application to do your work. It was one of those programs worth the money I paid for it.

Answer (score 1):

Navicat is a good MySQL editor and management application for windows.